# load the phenotype data for ballgown

Tags: rna-seq, bioconductor, differential-expression

I am trying to reproduce the work of [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2016.095)
[[1]](https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2016.095), and I have run StringTie successfully, but after that I have to run Ballgown but could not understand this command:

```
>pheno_data = read.csv("geuvadis_phenodata.csv")
```

Actually, I dont know how to make the .csv file of my samples. What phenotype information should this csv contain?

I have checked the supplementary data of this research article but didn't find any .csv file.

How I can make the .csv file for my samples to load the phenotype data for ballgown?

> 8. Load the phenotype data for the samples. An example file called
>      geuvadis_phenodata.csv is included with the data files for this protocol
>      (ChrX_data). In general, you will have to create this file yourself. It contains
>      information about your RNA sequencing samples, formatted as illustrated in
>      this csv (comma-separated values) file. Each sample should be described on
>      one row of the file and each column should contain one variable. To read this
>      file into R we use the command read.csv. In this file the values are
>      separated by commas, but if the file were tabdelimited you could use the
>      function read.table.
>
>    > pheno_data = read.csv("geuvadis_phenodata.csv")

---

1. Pertea *et al*, Transcript-level expression analysis of RNA-seq experiments with HISAT, StringTie and Ballgown, *Nature Protocols* volume 11, pages 1650–1667 (2016)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it via Notepad++ or even Excel. Just don't forget to save the output file as a `.csv` file (comma-separated value). 
The info inside should look like (my working example):

```
id,state
lar_control141,control
lar_control142,control
lar_control143,control
lar_probiotic142,probiotic
lar_probiotic143,probiotic
lar_probiotic144,probiotic
lar_probiotic145,probiotic
lar_probiotic146,probiotic
```

That should work